# Laravel deployment and update on Apache Webserver

Tags: laravel, deployment

I want to get my Larvel project ready for deployment.
I already found some guides in the web, but no one of them could answer me the following question(s):

**Which file do I have to upload to the webserver?**

I already tried to remove as much folders/files as possible to keep the project-size on my apache webserver as small as possible. But is there any guide which tells me, which folders/files do i exactly need to exchange?

**When it comes to an update:**

Once deployed, which files do i need to update?
Do I have to upload all the files again or can I exchange only certain ones?

Currently i followed the official laravel guide and uploaded all files to the webserver.

Comment: What sever (VPS or Shared) are you deploying the site on?! and do you have SSH access to the server?!

Comment: Currently i have access only via ftp. Would SSH bring some improvements with it when deploying the project?

Comment: Yes with ftp access, you have to manually upload everything and with ssh you can use composer to install vendors and can even use php artisan command. I'll share the link to my answer (that I have already answered regarding this), hope it helps!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919167/what-is-the-easiest-and-quickest-method-to-deploy-a-laravel-web-application-live/53919886#53919886

Comment: Actually my question was which of the many folders i have to upload and 
since not all files are needed on the server but thanks for your answer!

Comment: With only FTP access, you have no choice but to upload all folders that you have on your local machine!!!

Comment: This is not true - for many folders like node_modules, content of storage-folder, and some more there is no need to be deployed

Comment: For `node_modules` you have to upload the folder if you'll be using any of the npm dependencies in your project as the FTP account without SSH access doesn't allow you to do the install online and for `storage-folder`, if you have any files uploaded and stored like images or documents that you'll need in production then you have to upload it else you can ignore but if there is nothing in folder, then it will be like < 2kb so why not just upload it with the rest!!!